# ASPx control focus not working

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I want to apply an effect on focus upon a `<dx:ASPxTextBox control>`. Here is what I tried :

```
<dx:ASPxTextBox ID="tb_name" runat="server" Focused-CssClass="txtBox"></dx:ASPxTextBox>
```

And here is my focused class css :

```
<style>
    .txtBox:focus {
        border-color : red;
        transition : 0.5s linear;
    }
</style>
```

When I try it, it seems the focus state of my css isn't applied when I click on my textBox. I tried the exact same with a simple `<asp:TextBox>` and it works well, so my css isn't involved.

How can I perform this with a DevelopperExpress control `<dx:ASPxTextBox>` ?

Comment: Does it work with a regular CSS class?

Comment: This does not works either with a minimal css class like "border-color : blue" or whathever simple.

Comment: There is an example of how to do this on the company's website - https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q558238 - are you sure there is a `Focused-CssClass` property on the main element, vs a child element `<FocusedStyle CssClass="focusedTextBox"></FocusedStyle>`?

Comment: Thanks Darren, it works with <FocusedStyle>. The only thing was I should not set a txtBox:focused, but create another class especially dedicated to the focus state.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Darren, the solution is to separate the :focus state in a single css class. Here is the step to do :

```
<dx:ASPxTextBox ID="tb_name" runat=server" CssClass="txtBox">
    <FocusedStyle CssClass="txtBoxFocused"></FocusedStyle>
</dx:ASPxTextBox>
```

The focus state isn't shared with the "basic" state. And here is the css :

```
<style>
    .txtBox {
        border-color : black;
        border-width : 1px;
        transition : 0.5s linear;
    }

    .txtBoxFocused {
        border-color : red;
        border-width : 1px;
        transition : 0.5s linear;
    }
</style>
```